# xCode says the object might not respond to selector while I'm checking for it

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have the following code:

```
if([node respondsToSelector:@selector(setOpacity:)])
    [node setOpacity:127];
```

I know `node` might not respond to `setOpacity:` so I check for it, but xCode still warns against it. is there any way of safely calling the selector without xCode complaining? the warning is:

> /path/file.mm:79: warning: 'CCNode' may not respond to '-setOpacity:'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if([someIndexes respondsToSelector:@selector(setOpacity:)])
    [(id)someIndexes setOpacity:127];
```

Comment: @Dani, i couldn't disagree more. If you want specific type checking, you use a specific type. If you don't want the compiler to type check you use a more general type. This is exactly why this functionality exists - to let you the programmer choose.